# How to return a object properties through a Result

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-mvc-5.1, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I am trying to Get all the properties of a object. I am not sure how to do this with the type of relationship I am using. I am returning all of the Jobs in the db. Jobs has a one-to-many relationship with the CustomerEmployee class. I need all of the properties in the CustomerEmployee class accessible through the Job list. I have managed to get the First & Last Name of the CustomerEmployee but I don't see how I can access the other properties using this way. So I don't know if I need to change the way I have the relationship setup? Which leads me to my next question, when I make a new Job Post, the foreign key is not being inserted in the right column. The db has two different columns.example, "JobTESPMId" & "JobTESPMId_EmployeeId". I need the Id inserted in the "JobTESPMId_EmployeeId" but it is being inserted in the other one. I got kind of lost when setting this up so I would like to understand why this is happening.

```
public class Job
{
    public Int64? JobId { get; set; }
    public int? JobNumber { get; set; }
    public string JobName { get; set; }
    public string JobDescription { get; set; }

    public int? GeoAreaId { get; set; }
    public virtual JobMisc.GeoArea GeoArea { get; set; }

    public int? JobClassId { get; set; }
    public virtual JobMisc.JobClass JobClass { get; set; }

    public int? JobTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual JobMisc.JobType JobType { get; set; }

    public Int64? CustomerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ChangeOrder> ChangeOrders { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PurchaseOrder> PurchaseOrders { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<JobItem> JobItems { get; set; }

    public int? CustomerEmployeePMId { get; set; }
    public virtual CustomerEmployee CustomerEmployeePM { get; set; }

    public int? CustomerEmployeeAdminId { get; set; }
    public virtual CustomerEmployee CustomerEmployeeAdmin { get; set; }

    public int? CustomerEmployeeAccountantId { get; set; }
    public virtual CustomerEmployee CustomerEmployeeAccountant { get; set; }

    public int? CustomerEmployeeSuperintendentId { get; set; }
    public virtual CustomerEmployee CustomerEmployeeSuperintendent { get; set; }

    public int? JobTESPMId { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee JobTESPM { get; set; }

    public int? JobTESSuperintendentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee JobTESSuperintendent { get; set; }
}
```

CustomerEmployee

```
public class CustomerEmployee
{
    [Key]
    public int CustomerEmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerEmployeeFirstName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerEmployeeLastName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerEmployeeEmail { get; set; }
    public Int64? CustomerEmployeePhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public Int64? CustomerEmployeeCellNumber { get; set; }
    public Int64? CustomerEmployeeFaxNumber { get; set; }
    public bool? CustomerEmployeeIsHidden { get; set; }
    public string CustomerEmployeeRole { get; set; }

    public Int64? CustomerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }

}
```

ViewModel/Result

```
 public class JobViewModel
  {
    public Int64? JobId { get; set; }
    public int? JobNumber { get; set; }
    public string JobName { get; set; }
    public decimal? JobOriginalContract { get; set; }
    public DateTime? JobContractDate { get; set; }
    public decimal? JobTotalCO { get; set; }
    public decimal? JobRevisedContract { get; set; }
    public decimal? JobOriginalBudget { get; set; }
    public string JobStatus { get; set; }
    public bool? JobTaxExempt { get; set; }
    public bool? JobCertPayroll { get; set; }
    public decimal? JobCost { get; set; }
    public decimal? JobRemainingBudget { get; set; }
    public decimal? JobProfit { get; set; }
    public decimal? JobPercentage { get; set; }
    public decimal? JobTotalBilled { get; set; }
    public decimal? JobBalanceToBill { get; set; }
    public decimal? JobPaidToDate { get; set; }
    public decimal? JobBalanceDue { get; set; }
    public bool? JobIsHidden { get; set; }


    public string Customer { get; set; }
    public string CustomerEmployeePM { get; set; }
    public string JobTESPM { get; set; }
    public string JobTESSuperintendent { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ChangeOrder> ChangeOrders { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<PurchaseOrder> PurchaseOrders { get; set; }

  }

 public class JobResult
  {
    public Int64? JobId { get; set; }
    public int? JobNumber { get; set; }
    public string JobName { get; set; }
    public decimal? JobOriginalContract { get; set; }
    public DateTime? JobContractDate { get; set; }
    public decimal? JobTotalCO { get; set; }
    public decimal? JobRevisedContract { get; set; }
    public decimal? JobOriginalBudget { get; set; }
    public string JobStatus { get; set; }
    public bool? JobTaxExempt { get; set; }
    public bool? JobCertPayroll { get; set; }
    public decimal? JobCost { get; set; }
    public decimal? JobRemainingBudget { get; set; }
    public decimal? JobProfit { get; set; }
    public decimal? JobPercentage { get; set; }
    public decimal? JobTotalBilled { get; set; }
    public decimal? JobBalanceToBill { get; set; }
    public decimal? JobPaidToDate { get; set; }
    public decimal? JobBalanceDue { get; set; }
    public bool? JobIsHidden { get; set; }


    public string Customer { get; set; }
    public string CustomerEmployeePM { get; set; }
    public string JobTESPM { get; set; }
    public string JobTESSuperintendent { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ChangeOrder> ChangeOrders { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<PurchaseOrder> PurchaseOrders { get; set; }
 }
```

apiController

```
// GET api/<controller>
    public IEnumerable<JobResult> Get()
    {
        using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            return context.Jobs
                .Include(x => x.Customer)
                .Include(x => x.ChangeOrders)
                .Include(x => x.PurchaseOrders)
                .Include(x => x.CustomerEmployeePM)
                .Include(x => x.JobTESPM)
                .Include(x => x.JobTESSuperintendent)

                .ToResults();
        }

    }
```

JSON

```
0: {$id: "1", JobId: 2, JobNumber: 3244, JobName: "Job Alpha", JobOriginalContract: 34343443,…}
$id: "1"
ChangeOrders: [,…]
Customer: "Twin Peaks"
CustomerEmployeePM: "Kelly Young"
JobId: 2
JobName: "Job Alpha"
JobNumber: 3244
JobTESPM: "Laura Mince"
JobTESSuperintendent: "Scott Willis"
JobTaxExempt: true
JobTotalBilled: null
PurchaseOrders: []
1: {$id: "3", JobId: 9, JobNumber: 342, JobName: "sad", JobOriginalContract: 323232,…}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return context.Jobs
                .Include(x => x.Customer)
                .Include(x => x.ChangeOrders)
                .Include(x => x.PurchaseOrders)
                .Include(x => x.CustomerEmployeePM)
                .Include(x => x.JobTESPM)
                .Include(x => x.JobTESSuperintendent)

                .ToList();
```

is what you need

Comment: When I change it to List, I get this  Error 2 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<TexasExteriorSPA.Models.Job>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TexasExteriorSPA.Models.JobResult>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) C:\Development\TexasExteriorSPA\TexasExteriorSPA\ApiControllers\apiJobController.cs 34 21 TexasExteriorSPA

Answer (score 0):

Possibly one quick answer, if your JobResult class had a constructor that allowed you to map from Job to JobResult then it would be as simple as

```
return context.Jobs
  .Select(j => new JobResult(j));
```

or if you prefer a less coupled way...

```
return context.Jobs
  .Select(j => new JobResult(j.Customer, j.ChangeOrders, j.PurchaseOrders, etc.));
```

Essentially you're dealing with mapping from one type to another. This sort of mapping work is also how you'd solve your second question.

Edit: a little hazy on my EF abilities, but you may need an empty constructor, in which case something like this...I sort of forgot what's allowed in a linq query but I know an empty constructor works.

```
return context.Jobs
  .Select(j => new JobResult() { j.Customer, j.ChangeOrders, j.PurchaseOrders, etc.} );
```

Failing that, and if you know you want ALL jobs without paging/filtering up the chain then...

```
return context.Jobs
  .ToList()
  .Select(j => new JobResult() { j.Customer, j.ChangeOrders, j.PurchaseOrders, etc.} );
```

Comment: how would i add a constructor to the Result class?